# Nested struct for UITableView Swift/JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, uitableview, decodable

I need to display topic and description in a UITableView.

```
struct Topics: Decodable {

let subtopics: [subTopic]

    struct subTopic: Decodable {
     
      var topic = ""
      var description = ""

    }
}
```

The data for the TableView is fetched with a URL post request and assigned inside a `do/try/catch` block.

```
let Topics = Topics()
```

excerpt from URLRequest:

```
 self.Topics =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Topics.self, from: data)
```

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topicCell") as! topicCell

var subTopic = Topics?.subtopics[indexPath.row]

cell.topicLabel?.text = subTopic.topic
cell.descriptionTextView?.text = subTopic.description


return cell 
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return Topics?.subtopics.count
}
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"subtopics":[{"topic":"Computer Science", "description":"beginner course"},{"topic":"Data Analysis", "description":"beginner course"}]}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code? Do you have a compiler error? I suspect one: `return Topics?.subtopics.count`, missing `?? 0`, ie, it should returns 0 if there is no `Topics` is nil.

Comment: @Larme Error is ```JSON errortypeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))```

Answer (score 1):

You give the the variable the same name as the struct.

```
let Topics = Topics()
```

**Don't do that.** It is confusing and can cause unexpected behavior.
There is a reason for the naming convention to name variables lowercase and structs/classes uppercase.

For less confusion name the top object different for example

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    
    let subtopics: [SubTopic]
    
    struct SubTopic: Decodable {
        
        let topic, description : String
        
    }
}
```

The default values (and `var`iables) in `SubTopic` make no sense.

My next recommendation is to omit the top object and declare the data source array

```
var subTopics = [Response.SubTopic]()
```

and assign

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
self.subTopics = response.subtopics
```

This will clean up the table view code and gets rid of the ugly optionals

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topicCell") as! topicCell

    let subTopic = subTopics[indexPath.row]
    cell.topicLabel?.text = subTopic.topic
    cell.descriptionTextView?.text = subTopic.description

    return cell 
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return subTopics.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot vadian! The data is successfully printed out but the tableView doesn't show on the ViewController in Simulation. No errors... Printing `subTopic.topic` was also blank

Comment: You have to call `reloadData()` on the table view after populating the data source array.

Comment: oh man, forgot that. Now its working. Appreciate your help!

Comment: in the `didSelectRowAt` func I am assigning `subTopic.topic` to a global variable and then assigning the global variable in the `prepare` -segue function to the Label of the DetailViewController but I end up getting the data from the previous cell? Any ideas or should I post the complete code?

Comment: This is a another question. Basically you don't need a global variable by passing the index path in the `sender` parameter to `prepare(for`